# Clear textbox within multi-page userform when textbox is clicked on

Tags: vba, textbox, userform, multipage

I'm having a slight problem with some VBA coding on a multi-page userform I'm creating. I have some textboxes on each page of the userform, and I had code that I had been using with regular userforms to clear the textboxes provided in the following answer to another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8921247/2477891)

The code looks like this:

```
Sub TB_enter(TB_name)
    If Len(Me.Controls(TB_name).Tag) = 0 Then
        Me.Controls(TB_name).Tag = Me.Controls(TB_name).Value
        Me.Controls(TB_name).Value = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub

Sub TB_exit(TB_name)
    'When you click out of the textbox and no information has been entered, returns original text
    If Len(Me.Controls(TB_name).Value) = 0 Then
        Me.Controls(TB_name).Value = Me.Controls(TB_name).Tag
        Me.Controls(TB_name).Tag = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```

Along with the following code used for the textboxes to clear them:

```
Private Sub AdNtbx_Enter()
TB_enter ActiveControl.Name
End Sub

Private Sub AdNtbx_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    TB_exit ActiveControl.Name
End Sub
```

My problem is that they are no longer working because they are on multi-pages, and the following line comes up with an error:

```
Me.Controls(TB_name).Value = vbNullString
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be the problem/solution?

I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: my guess is that you have to iterate over the tabs now. it check out the tab control properties for easy access to the tabs

Comment: Do you mean replacing Me with the tab name? Also, when you you say 'it check out the tab control properties', what do you mean? Sorry if I seem a bit slow, caffeine has yet to kick in.

Comment: i mean that you have to qualify each textbox. If you have a multi-page (multi-tab) userform. then each of the textboxes belongs to a separate page. So I am think `Me.Controls...` should now become something like `Me.MultiPageControl(page_index).TextBox(textbox_index)` or `Me.MultipageControl(index).Controls(text_box_name)`. I am sorry i do not have enough time to provide a complete solution but i hope ive given you a hint to where to being

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for :

```
  Set Page1 = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Designer.Controls("Multipage1").Pages("Page1")
  Page1.textbox1.Text = vbNullString
```

You can edit ThisWorkbook, UserForm1 etc.. properties to suit your needs, but with this code you will be able clear textboxes on multipage object