# VBA Placeholder text that disappears only upon typing, not when entering textbox on UserFrom

Tags: excel, vba, placeholder

' I'm looking to create placeholder text (ghosting text) to help users know what to type in the field, but I want it to act very similar to on-line forms where the placeholder text does not disappear upon entering a textbox, but only disappears if you type new text into it.

```
' enterfieldbehavior is set to 1 -  fmEnterFieldBehaviorRecallSelection in properties to avoid selecting placeholder text

Private Sub userform_initialize()
    TextBox2.Value = "Name" 'upon starting UserForm, the placeholder text is launched in the textbox
    TextBox2.ForeColor = &H8000000C 'grey

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    If TextBox2.Text <> "Name" Then
        TextBox2.SelStart = TextBox2.SelLength 'Upon entering the textbox, the cursor is placed only at the start and not the middle or end of the placeholder text
    Else
    ' I need the oppositie of the above, to put the cursor at the end of text as the placeholder text is gone
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        TextBox2.SelStart = TextBox2.SelLength ' If a user uses the mouse to enter the textbox

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    If TextBox2.Text <> "Name" Then
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox2.ForeColor = &H8000000C 'grey
        Else
            TextBox2.Value = TextBox2.Value ' This is where I'm lost as I want to earse the holder text, and let the user type whatever they want
            TextBox2.ForeColor = vbBlack
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        TextBox2.Text = "Name" ' If there are no changes to the textbox, replace the placeholder text
        TextBox2.ForeColor = &H8000000C 'grey
        Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text box prompt text in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514760/text-box-prompt-text-in-excel-vba)

Comment: If the text is empty or is equal to "Name", then set text = "Name" and color to grey. Else, just set the color to black (and the text will be set by the control itself).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   Label1.Visible = Len(TextBox1.Text) = 0
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Label1.Visible = Len(TextBox1.Text) = 0
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Label1
        .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
        .BackColor = vbGrayText
        .Caption = "    Name"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Classic thinking.and also classic command over syntax in exit event.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution in **only 1 line of code** is:

- Duplicate (copy/paste) your `TextBox2` and name it e.g. `TextBox2PlaceHolder`
- Set its `Text` property to whatever placeholder value you want, eg. "YYYY/MM/DD"
- Set its `Enabled` property to `False` so that text color will be light gray
- Send it to the background just behind your original `TextBox2` (same Left and Top properties)

And finally, the masterpiece of code below will just switch the `TextBox2.BackStyle` to transparent if no text exists and so will let the placeholder appear!

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    TextBox2.BackStyle = IIf(Len(TextBox2.Text) = 0, fmBackStyleTransparent, fmBackStyleOpaque)
End Sub
```

Here's what that looks like:
[image: gif showing placeholder text vanishing]